# Was the main character in Gigi based on a real-life person?

Tags: french-language, inspiration, colette

Gigi, the female protagonist of Colette's novella [*Gigi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigi_(novella)) (1944), is full of character. Independent and mischievous, and a little tomboyish, she leaves a lasting impression on the reader. I am wondering if she was based on a real person in [Colette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colette)'s life?

Colette grew up in Burgundy and seems to have lived in Paris and known the city pretty well by the time *Gigi* came out. I am not sure Gigi would have been considered a typical Parisian girl at that time, but she certainly comes off as an interesting character to the modern reader.